# Convert concurrentqueue of class objects to observablecollection of same object

Tags: c#, multithreading, observablecollection, uwp, concurrent-queue

I have a concurrentqueue which contains class objects, I want to take those objects and put them into a observable collection of the same class object. (basically copying/moving it from the concurrentqueue to the collection.)

Here I add the elements into the concurrent queue during a multithreaded process.

```
sTumblrblog_gv_concurqueue.Enqueue(new sTumblrblog_gv() { Title = tumblrusrfollow.Title, Url = tumblrusrfollow.Url.ToString(), AvatarImage = imageavatar, BlogPosts = blogposts, IsNsfw = blogisnfw });
```

And then I want to take them out of that and put them into an observable collection. Without any duplicate objects (or objects with the same url in them.

```
if (!sTumblrblog_gv_list.Any(p => p.Url == tumblrusrfollow.Url))
{
     sTumblrblog_gv Queue2ObsCollection =  new Queue2ObsCollection;
     Queue2ObsCollection =(sTumblrblog_gv)sTumblrblog_gv_concurqueue.TryDequeue();
     sTumblrblog_gv_list.Add(new sTumblrblog_gv() { Title = Queue2ObsCollection.Title , Url = Queue2ObsCollection.Url, AvatarImage = Queue2ObsCollection.AvatarImage, BlogPosts = Queue2ObsCollection.BlogPosts, IsNsfw = Queue2ObsCollection.IsNsfw});       
}
```

I currently get "Error  CS1526  A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type" This probably isn't the best way to do this and any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: In your code I think the line `sTumblrblog_gv Queue2ObsCollection =  new Queue2ObsCollection;` should be `sTumblrblog_gv Queue2ObsCollection =  new sTumblrblog_gv();` (or using other constructor).

Comment: When I try that and clean/rebuild I get just the 1 error
Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'result' of 'ConcurrentQueue<MainPage.sTumblrblog_gv>.TryDequeue(out MainPage.sTumblrblog_gv)'